# I don't understand this explanation on converting mph to meters per second. Can someone explain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics

[image: Here's the example/explanation.]

Wouldn't "60 x 60" covert to metres per minute? Can someone explain this more intuitively?

Comment: How many seconds are in an hour? That's what "$60 \times 60$" represents. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$90 \frac{miles}{hour}=90 \cdot \frac{miles}{60 \, minutes}=90 \cdot \frac{miles}{60 \cdot 60 \, seconds}= \frac{90}{60 \cdot 60} \cdot \frac{miles}{seconds}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{90\text{ mi.}}{1\text{ hr.}}\times \frac{1\text{ hr.}}{60\text{ min.}}\times \frac{1\text{ min.}}{60\text{ s}}\times\frac{1600 \text{ m}}{1\text{ mi.}}=\frac{90\times1600}{60\times60}\cdot\frac{\text{mi.}\times\text{hr.}\times\text{min.}\times\text{m}}{\text{hr.}\times\text{min.}\times\text{s}\times\text{mi.}} = 40 \text{ m/s}$$